# Oracle Sql Query with Group By

Tags: sql, oracle

select  employee from each departments whose name has minimum number of characters

For ex-

```
Name   Deaprtment
Raj     IT
Raja    IT
Shyam   IT
Ravi    CS
Ram     CS

Kamlesh EC
Ajay    EC
```

Then output should be

```
Name Department
Raj  IT
Ram  CS
Ajay EC
```

Since in IT Raj has least ie 3 characters and in CS Ram and similarly in EC Ajay
So how to write this query. I have tried a lot of things but not able to figure out.

Comment: Then add the last query you tried, what problems you have with it and possible errors you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description makes it sound like you are looking for the shortest name in each department.  If so, a relatively simple approach is to use `row_number()`:

```
select name, department
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by department order by length(name) desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```